# scraping with pd.read_html, returning ValueError: No tables found

Tags: pandas, web-scraping, python-requests, lxml

I've tried this a few different ways yielding the same results. I'm trying to scrape a table from the web and export to .csv, got this working for other websites, but not having much luck for some reason here. [website](https://www.oaklandyard.com/lg_standings/lg_standings.asp?LgSessCode=2731&ReturnPg=lg%5Fsoccer%5Fcoed%2Easp%232731&ShowRankings=False&HeaderTitle=&sw=1800)

Here is one of my attempts:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.oaklandyard.com/lg_standings/lg_standings.asp?LgSessCode=2731&ReturnPg=lg%5Fsoccer%5Fcoed%2Easp%232731&ShowRankings=False&HeaderTitle=&sw=1800'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.text
tables = pd.read_html(html)
tables[0].to_csv(test.csv, index=False)
```

I've tried using pandas to scrape this website print(html) returns the page source, but pandas is not seeing the tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `<table>` tag in the page you want to scrape. You have to process the page manually with `requests` and `bs4`:

```
import requests
import bs4
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.oaklandyard.com/lg_standings/lg_standings.asp?LgSessCode=2731&ReturnPg=lg%5Fsoccer%5Fcoed%2Easp%232731&ShowRankings=False&HeaderTitle=&sw=1800'

response = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)
table = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'divLargeTable'})[1]
rows = table.find_all('div', {'class': 'divMultipleColumns'})
headers = [title.text for title in rows[0].find_all('div', {'class': 'standingsTitle1'})]

data = {}
for row in rows[1:]:
    cols = row.find_all('div')
    index = cols[0].text.strip()
    data[index] = [int(value.text) for value in cols[1:]]
    
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index', columns=headers)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                       Wins  Losses  Ties  Scored  Allowed  Differential  Points
Old farts                 7       0     0      41       20            21      21
Killer Penguins           5       2     0      36       21            15      15
#BackHeelz                4       1     2      30       17            15      14
Misfits                   3       2     2      25       19             6      11
The Banshees              3       4     0      32       37            -5       9
Other Team Money Line     1       4     2      15       25           -10       5
Slackers                  1       5     1      18       27            -9       4
Shits & Dribbles          0       6     1      13       44           -31       1
```